# Rails 3: Storing Session in Active Record (not cookie)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

*I trawled google university for about an hour or so but there is no single good documentation on this topic :-(  Hoping someone can help. I am willing to buy a book as well as long as someone can tell me which one.*

I am using following versions:

- rails 3.2.6,
- ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]

To start using session storage in Active Record instead of cookie, I did following:

1. Update `config/initializers/session_store.rb`.
   *Commented first line and uncommented the last one, so I have:*

   ```
   # Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

   # Myapp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_elegato_session'

   # Use the database for sessions instead of the cookie-based default,
   # which shouldn't be used to store highly confidential information
   # (create the session table with "rails generate session_migration")
   Myapp::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store
   ```
2. `rake db:sessions:create`

   ```
   invoke  active_record
     create    db/migrate/20120729025112_add_sessions_table.rb
   ```
3. `rake db:migrate`

   ```
   ==  CreateLinkedinUsers: migrating ============================================
   -- create_table(:linkedin_users)
     -> 0.0236s
   ==  CreateLinkedinUsers: migrated (0.0237s) ===================================

   ==  AddSessionsTable: migrating ===============================================
   -- create_table(:sessions)
     -> 0.0012s
   -- add_index(:sessions, :session_id)
     -> 0.0006s
   -- add_index(:sessions, :updated_at)
     -> 0.0006s
   ==  AddSessionsTable: migrated (0.0026s) ======================================
   ```
4. To find out what table is actually created, I open the sqlite3 file

   ```
   sqlite> .schema sessions
   CREATE TABLE "sessions" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "session_id"   varchar(255) NOT NULL, "data" text, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL);
   CREATE INDEX "index_sessions_on_session_id" ON "sessions" ("session_id");
   CREATE INDEX "index_sessions_on_updated_at" ON "sessions" ("updated_at");
   ```

So, there is a "data" field in sessions table that will store everything related to the session.

### Now, onto my question :-)

I need to store values for 2 variables in session:  access_token and request_token.
Can I use following? (the way I used to store session values for a cookie)

```
session[:access_token] = <blah>
session[:request_token] = <some other blah?
```

And if it does work, does ruby store both variables in the "data" field of the table as an array.

Thanks much for your help!

Answer (score 4):

All of your session variables are serialized using Base64 in the data column of the sessions table. You can use it the same way as you would use it if you were assigning and retrieving values using the cookie session store. There are some nice benefits to storing session variables in the db, like only transmitting the session_id during each request, rather than the entire session from the cookie, the ability to manage stale or old sessions by checking their age (created_at/updated_at), and the ability to store more info than you can in a cookie.

You can provide your own Session class also, check the documentation in the SessionStore class: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5edfc463484827df364a1e589677d5c84dfac282/activerecord/lib/active_record/session_store.rb

Comment: Hardly surprising @sjors-branderhorst, since my answer is more than a year old, and Rails master is now at version 4. I should probably have grabbed the link for the tagged version instead - hindsight is wonderful thing. ActiveRecord::SessionStore has since been extracted out into it's own gem for Rails 4 - the new link is https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store.

Comment: For posterity, I've updated the link to point to the file as of the date of the comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

You generally don't have to care too much about how Rails stores the sessions, it's transparent. If you use the cookie store or the ActiveRecord store, your code will not change.

So yeah you can do what you were doing previously. And technically, a serialized string containing the session is stored in the `data` field, but it doesn't matter much :)

However I'd suggest using the cookie store, unless you have a good reason to use ActiveRecord (more than 4K data in session?)

Comment: Why would you suggest using the cookie store?

Comment: By default - with the cookie store, unless you change something the session will not expire. That means that some default applications may be vulnerable to replay attacks. It also means that sensitive information should never be put in the session.
The best practice is to use a database based session. See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Ruby_on_Rails_Cheatsheet#Sessions

Comment: Rails' default is still the cookie store and the main reason is speed. You also don't have to care about your db size growing. That said, you have to know the good practices to use it. Don't store anything secret in there (why would you though?), and don't store any serialized objects. Just store ids or you'll burst the 4K limit very quickly. I agree with you that the DB store is way easier to deal with on smaller projects. At scale though, the cookie store is tremendously faster. This URL : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-storage is a good read on the subject.