# Session usage in rails 3.1.3, returning errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session-cookies

I am in a process of upgrading my app from rails 2.3.11 to 3.2.x. Everything worked well untill 3.1.x where I faced issues in session handling. Earlier I have utilized cookies for session handling but now there is a question if I can use ActiveModel for handling sessions too?????

Secondly, while still playing around with cookies, I see this unavoidable undefined method error. Any suggestions to get around this error????

Here is my codes-

Session Controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController


def new
  @title = "Sign in"
end

def create
   @title = "create session"
   user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:name], params[:session][:password])
   if user.nil?     
   flash.now[:error] = "Invalid username/password combination."
   @title = "Sign in"
  render 'new'
 else     
   sign_in user      
   @partner = Partner.find(:first, :conditions => [ "user_id = ?", user.id])  
   logger.info "---------User loggin: " + current_user.name
   redirect_back_or samplings_url
 end
end

def destroy
  @title = "Sign out"
  logger.info "---------User log OUT: " + current_user.name
  sign_out
  redirect_to root_path
 end
end
```

User Model:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessor :password



    attr_accessible :name, :email, :password

    EmailRegex = /\A[\w+\-._]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

    validates_presence_of :name, :email
    validates_length_of   :name, :maximum => 50

    validates_format_of   :email, :with => EmailRegex
    validates_uniqueness_of :email, :case_sensitive => false
    has_many :microposts
    validates_confirmation_of :password
    validates_presence_of :password
    validates_length_of   :password, :within => 1..40
    before_save :encrypt_password

    def self.authenticate(name, submitted_password)  
        username = self.where(name: name)
        return nil  if username.nil?
        return username if username.encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
    end

    def remember_me!          
        self.remember_token = encrypt("#{salt}--#{id}--#{Time.now.utc}")
        save(validate=false)
    end

 private


    def encrypt_password
        unless password.nil? #due to def remember_me! method during sign in function call
    self.salt = make_salt
    self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)   
       end
    end

    def encrypt(string)
        secure_hash("#{salt}#{string}")
    end

    def make_salt
        secure_hash("#{Time.now.utc}#{password}")
    end

    def secure_hash(string)
         Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
    end

 end
```

UserController:

```
     class UsersController < AuthController

           before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:index, :edit, :update]
           before_filter :correct_user, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]
           before_filter :modify_user, :only => [:edit, :update]


              filter_parameter_logging :password


        def index
            @users = User.all
            @title = "users"

            respond_to do |format|
            format.html # index.html.erb
            format.xml  { render :xml => @users }
            end
        end


        def show
            @user = User.find(params[:id])
            @title = @user.name

            respond_to do |format|
            format.html # show.html.erb
            format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
            end
        end


       def new
           redirect_to signin_path    
           if !current_user?(@user)
           flash[:notice] = "Only the partner who create the risorse can modify it."
           end  
       end

       def create
           @title = "sign up user"
           @user = User.new(params[:user])  #hash of user attributes
           if @user.save
             sign_in @user
             flash[:success] = "Welcome to the microaqua web application!"
             redirect_to @user  #equal as user_path(@user)
           else
             @title = "Sign up"
             render 'new'
           end
        end


         # GET /users/1/edit
         def edit
            @title = @user.name #"user"
         end

        def update
            @title = @user.name #"user"

           if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
              flash[:success] = "Profile updated."
              redirect_to @user
           else
             @title = "Edit user"
             render 'edit'
             end
           end

          def destroy
            redirect_to users_path
          end

     private

          def correct_user
            @user = User.find(params[:id])
            reroute() unless signed_in_and_master?
          end

         def modify_user
             @user = User.find(params[:id])
             reroute() unless (current_user?(@user) or signed_in_and_master?)
         end

         def reroute()
             flash[:notice] = "Only the partner can modify his own profile."
             redirect_to(user_path(@user))
         end
      end
```

Error:

```
      NoMethodError in SessionsController#create

       undefined method `encrypted_password' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x00000003632038>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.where` always returns an array. Here is the code that is throwing the error in your user model:

```
def self.authenticate(name, submitted_password)  
    username = self.where(name: name)
    return nil  if username.nil?
    return username if username.encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
end
```

You are calling `.encrypted_password` on an array.  Change the code to this:

```
def self.authenticate(name, submitted_password)  
    username = self.where(name: name).first
    return nil  if username.nil?
    return username if username.encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
end
```

If it is possible to get more than one user with the same name then you should iterate through the array and check every result.

As far as storing the session in the database, check out this SO question:[Rails 3: Storing Session in Active Record (not cookie)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706297/rails-3-storing-session-in-active-record-not-cookie)